# Неправильная кодировка mysql

Tags: mysql, кодировка

В базе данных русский текст меняется на unicod(например вместо слова "Привет" выдает "u041fu0440u0438u0432u0435u0442"). Английский текст кодирует нормально. Где только можно стоит utf-8. Кодировка самого поля utf8-general-ci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему utf8-general-ci это не кодировка, это "collation". Насколько я знаю этот параметр определеяет способ сопоставления(сортировки, сравнения и пр.).

Вы уверены что проблема в базе, а не в способе подключения к ней? Обозначаете ли Вы требуемую кодировку при работе с базой?

Вот здесь тред, с которым Вам стоит ознакомиться.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/13468321